# Insert data from column of a table and store to column another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table `Source` and `details` with this column:

`Source id, item_name, items_download` `id` is primary key.

`details` name, download`and ...`name` is primary key.

I want to get data from Source table (in real time) and put into `details` table. This is my code:

```
$get= "INSERT INTO `details` (`name`,  `download`) SELECT `Source`.`item_name`,`Source`.`items_download` FROM `Source`"
```

The above code worked, but only for the first time and data inserted, when I refresh the page I got this error:

```
Duplicate entry 'Test1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: That's expected to happen. You're duplicating the data being inserted again. That can't be what you want.

Comment: I think this is another _Stop, Think, Refactor_ situation

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thank you for reply. do you have another ida to do this?

Comment: your primary key should be a numeric auto increment index, it's simple and efficent and no need to worry about multiple inserts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asked for the UPDATE to check, if you want to know whether the database-table was imported OR updated, run this SCRIPT first:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS countOfDetails 
FROM 
    details
```

In PHP:

```
$messageString = "";
// assign the countOfDetails from the Query to a PHP variable $myCount
if($myCount==0){
    $messageString = "Database Imported Successfully!";
}
else{
    $messageString = "Database Updated Successfully!";
}
```

After getting the message to be displayed in a string.

You can run this SCRIPT to update/import the Database Table:

```
INSERT INTO details (name, download) 
SELECT item_name, items_download
FROM Source
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
          ( SELECT name, download FROM details 
            WHERE name IN (
                       SELECT item_name FROM Source
                          )
          )
```

After you have Run it, echo the `$messageString` wherever you want.

---

**NOTE:** This will insert the rows that are not present in the details table (and won't give an error and will skip the INSERT part if it already exists), so the error of Duplication will be not given in any case and the work will be done

Comment: just for learning more can you please tell me how can I show message. for first time display this message "Database successfully imported" and for updates "records successfully updates". Thank you so much

Comment: well, it depends on, when are you going to display the message. I mean to ask, how is the database going to be imported (on page load or a user clicks a button to update the above table

Comment: before running the **SCRIPT** which is mentioned in the **ANSWER**, you'll have to check if the **DETAILS** table count(number of rows). if **COUNT** is equal to **0** then display the Data-imported. ELSE Data-updated

Comment: I tested before but not worked. I have problem at `if the DETAILS table count(number of rows)` section. can you please update the answer by adding the messages. thank you

Comment: Thank you so much, Can you also help me about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961611/insert-ip-address-of-downloaded-files-into-mysql this is relative to this qustion.