# Insert IP address of downloaded files into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

By according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899117/insert-data-from-column-of-a-table-and-store-to-column-another-table)  I have 2 table `Source` and `details` .

The `Source` table is as follows:

```
+----+----------+---------------+-----------+
| id | item_name|items_download | category  |
+----+----------+---------------+-----------+
|                                           |
+----+----------+---------------+-----------+
```

The `details` table is as follows:

```
+------+----------+-----+------+
| name | download | time| ip   |
+------+----------+-----+------+
|                              |
+------+----------+-----+------+
```

At first step I want to get data from Source table (in real time) and put into details table by this code:

```
$get= "INSERT INTO `details` (`name`,  `download`) SELECT `Source`.`item_name`,`Source`.`items_download` FROM `Source`"
```

At next step I want to get visitor IP address for each file.

for example if someone downloaded `testfile` I want to have this output:

```
+----------+---------+--------------+-----------+
|  name    | download |   time      |  ip       |
+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+
| testfile |     32   |download time|192.168.0.0|
+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+
| file2    |     0    |             |           |
+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+
```

To do this i use this code:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$update = "UPDATE details SET  ip = '$ip', dldate = NOW()"
```

But its happened for all files, all of the file get same IP and time. I know its need a condition `WHERE` but I don't know what should I type as a condition to get IP address for each file that download.

Comment: Sorry for my dumb question but is `UPDATE table set col=val1=val2` valid or just a typo? I'm serious because I already learned a lot here and that could be one more thing.

Comment: @PerlDog its valid you can test by yourself http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: No, @Martin is right. Mind the comma! You wrote `set device=ip=$ip , dldate=now()`. I was referring to the device part, not to the dldate part.

Comment: I deleted my comment and referenced the issue in my answer....

Answer (score 1):

Imho you don't need any UPDATE query. You just do an INSERT everytime a user requests a file:

```
<?php
$fileid = $_GET['fileid'];

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Source WHERE id=" . (int)$fileid;
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO details (name, download, time, ip) VALUES (?, ?, NOW(), ?)");
    $statement->execute(array(
        $row['item_name'], 
        $row['items_download'],
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    ));   

}
?>
```

Some hints on the code above:

- Use prepared statements - never inject any value directly into an SQL string.
- It might be useless to insert file_name and items_download into the details table everytime. You have this information in your table "Source" anyway. So usually you would just put Source.id into your details table.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'd tend to not bother recording the time at all and simply generate a timestamp column on row insert, something like `ALTER TABLE \`details\`
CHANGE \`time\` \`time\`
TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @Gerfried thank you so much. my script use MySQLi so Im not sure this worked for me

Comment: @Gerfried tested not worked. Can you please give me MySQL example

Comment: Your SELECT is surely redundant

Answer (score 1):

You should use your `id` column, which you have in your first table view, but it stragely disappears in the later ones.

Your `id` column should also be your `PRIMARY_KEY AUTO INCREMENT` column. Then each row has its own unique and indexed id. 
But aside from that, what do you use to identify which file the user downloads? If it's the filename then simply use that:

EDIT: Add an `id` column to your `details` table!

```
$update = "UPDATE details SET ip = '$ip', dldate = NOW() 
WHERE name = '$fileNameValue' LIMIT 1"
```

On a related note, you can *not* update multiple columns with the same shorthand reference of `device = ip = '$ip'` you have to specify each column in isolation and with an absolute target data to insert (here, the variable) .

If this is a typo you should edit and update your question.

Please also see Gerfried's answer regarding using prepared statements, they are the way you should be doing these things.

Comment: sorry it was typo. I tested your code and it not worked for me. $fileNameValue ?

Comment: `$fileNameValue` is whatever value(name) you give to the variable holding your filename string, I've not got the free time to write your code for you. And anyhow, if I write it all out for you to copy and paste it, you won't learn it for next time :-p :-) @Anoano

Comment: you right but I dont want you give me full code. files stored by data like WordPress  it means there are some subdir. I tested this `$fileNameValue = "/files/*/"` and didn't work.

Comment: @MalikAsif are you posting on the correct question/answer? hah

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the session of user when he downloads the file and add it to the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you please give me an example